# Which Pattern to choose ? Asp.net Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

I'm really confused, I learned with the book "Apress pro Asp.net Mvc 4", that the best pattern for Mvc 4, is the Dependency Injection, ( to put the Model data of the database etc... in another project (Domain) and then create interfaces and implementation to those interfaces, and then connect it to the controller with Ninja..

And all the connect to the db is only from the data-layer solution, the only model in the web solution in viewModel

The Controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{

    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }
    ....
}
```

and Ninject

```
 ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
```

and on the other hand, In my last job(webmaster) , the company used another pattern for the mvc Projects (I'm using this pattern right now).

the projects is made with only One Solution and using Static Classes to handle the data layer

I don't like the Dependency Injection, this is too complicated, and by 'f12' you see only the interface instead of the Concrete class

**Some questions:**

1. which patter is better for performance (fast website)?
2. is't good to use "  public Db db = new Db();" in the controller, instead of use it only in the domain layer (solution)??
3. What is the advantages of using Dependency Injection? is't bad to use my pattern?
4. What is the advantages of split the project into 2 solutions for the Data Layer?

example:

```
 public class LanguageController : AdminController
    {
         public Db db = new Db();

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Admin/Language/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Languages.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(short id)
        {
            Language language = db.Languages.Find(id);
            db.Languages.Remove(language);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556967/accessing-database-entities-from-controller/17559336#17559336

Comment: Dependency injection is about code maintainability and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). It has nothing to do with application speed. In fact, it technically might slow your application down, even if only infinitesimally. However, that doesn't mean it's not still recommended. Or like any other pattern, you can go a completely different way just as well.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, is't really necessary to use the Dependency Injection?? I don't like it, it is too complicated, and by 'f12' you see only the interface instead of the Concrete class, what is the advantage of the Dependency Injection and the plit the project into domain model?

Comment: You don't need an interface for Dependency Injection, just inject your concrete class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which patter is better for performance (fast website)?

Impossible to answer.  You could have non-performant code in either of these approaches.  Don't try to prematurely optimize for performance, optimize for clean and supportable code and address performance bottlenecks that are actually observed in real scenarios.

> is't good to use " public Db db = new Db();" in the controller, instead of use it only in the domain layer (solution)

It's a question of separating concerns and isolating dependencies.  If your controller internally instantiates a connection to a database then that controller can *only ever* be used in the context of that database.  This will make unit testing the controller very difficult.  It also means that replacing the database means modifying the controller, which shouldn't need to be modified in that case.

Dependency injection frameworks are simply a way of addressing the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).  The idea is that if Object A (the controller) needs an instance of Object B (the database object) then it should require that the instance be supplied to it, rather than internally instantiate it.  The immediate benefit here is that Object B can just be an interface or abstract class which could have many different implementations.  Object A shouldn't care which implementation is given to it, as long as it satisfies the same observable behavior.

By inverting the dependency (whether or not you use a dependency injection framework), you remove the dependency on the database from the controller.  The controller just handles client-initiated requests.  Something else handles the database dependency.  This makes these two separate objects more portable and re-usable.

> What is the advantages of using Dependency Injection? is't bad to use my pattern?

See above.  Dependency injection is a way to achieve inversion of dependencies, which is the core goal in this case.  Note that there are a few different ways to achieve this.  Some frameworks prefer constructor injection, some support property/setter injection, etc.  Personally I tend to go with the service locator pattern, which has the added benefit of being able to abstract the dependency of the dependency injector itself.

It's only "bad" to use your approach if you run into any problems when using it.  There are good patterns to address various concerns, but if your project doesn't legitimately *have* those concerns then using those patterns would be over-engineering and would actually hurt the supportability of the code.  So, as with anything, "it depends."

> What is the advantages of split the project into 2 solutions for the Data Layer?

Two solutions?  Or two *projects* in the same *solution*?  (Resulting in two assemblies.)  The advantage is that you can re-use one without having a dependency on the other.  For example, in some of the code you posted there is an allusion to the repository pattern.  If you have an assembly which serves only the purpose of implementing repositories to the back-end data then any application can use those repositories.  If instead it's all implemented in the MVC application directly then no other application can use it, it's tightly coupled to the MVC application.

If you will never need to re-use that functionality, then this isn't the end of the world.  If you would like to re-use that functionality, separating it into a portable assembly which internally isolates its dependencies would allow for that.

Comment: @DanielEzra: Done.  It seems that what you're looking for is some introductory tutorials and examples for dependency injection.  You're asking a decent question, but it's at a *very* conceptual level.  The only advice I can really give is to practice and see where it takes you.  I personally use dependency injection a lot in my code, but most of what I write benefits from using it.  Not every project would benefit from it.  Like anything else, a dependency injection framework is a tool.  It should be applied (and applied correctly) only where it's beneficial.

Comment: @David +1 for that last sentence

Comment: @CharlieBrown: while advocatiing for DI unconditionally doesn't sound good, in most cases newbies benefit from learning and followind this principle. Note that for a newbie the "only where it is beneficial" doesn't really mean much and should probably not be read as "do not use if you don't understand". My experience in tutoring is that developers benefit from learning and following DI and rare cases where they don't were always caused just by DI being too difficult (surprisingly this is possible).

Comment: @WiktorZychla Your point is well made. Not only should DI be learned early and often, it should be so common that we don't need a special name for it. We should just be calling it, "What you do because its the right way to do it". DI helps ensure one of the bext principles of software development; Single Responsibility Principle. DI helps you separate the concerns so that each class has only one responsibility, and thus, ONE AND ONLY ONE reason to change.

Comment: @David you said " Not every project would benefit from it", so which projects need it?

Comment: @DanielEzra: That's a very subjective and case-by-case determination.  And as Wiktor insightfully points out, one can't really expect someone who isn't familiar with the pattern to successfully make that determination.  The best thing you can do is implement it in some side projects and get a feel for the benefits it provides as well as the challenges and changes it presents.  If the benefits outweigh the challenges, it's probably a good fit for the project.

Comment: So if the Dependency injection I will use it in the future,but not now, soon I start to learn "Management and computer science" In the university, so I will learn object oriented deeply in the future.